# Await.result(xxx, Duration.Inf).json giving me the error

Tags: json, scala

i am using `Scala-Play framework` where i am trying to get data from other websites but `Await.result(xxx, Duration.Inf).json` this particular line is showing me the error `JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60))` here is my code

```
var list:List[String]  = List();
var Url = "http://www.xxxxxx"
val Response = ws.url(Url).get()
val data = Await.result(Response, Duration.Inf).json
```

someone help me in this

for HTML Scraping 
i am using these libraries

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Extract._
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.dsl.DSL.Parse._

import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
import play.api.libs.ws.WSResponse
```

Comment: Iam not sure if Await is a good idea firstly. The problem here is the content that you have doesnt have a proper Json structure

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the url using a normal browser and see if the response is a valid json response. The error says that the response you got from Await.result(Response, Duration.Inf) is not a valid json.

Comment: in the browser console it is not printing any thing means no response

Comment: @raja not in the console do you see anything in the main window?

Answer (score 0):

`Response` doesn't contain a valid json. Check if URL is giving correct json on `GET`